# PHP Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in

Tags: php

I get the following error bellow and was wondering how can I correct this error

```
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in
```

PHP code

```
$number = '1,200.91';
$number = str_replace(',', '', $number);
$number = number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');

if(strlen($number) = 7){
    echo $number;
}
```

Comment: replace if(strlen($number) = 7){ to if(strlen($number) == 7){, put "=="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

= is not the same as ==

Code should be like this: `if(strlen($number) == 7){`

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I missed that its been a long night.

Comment: Well... it can happen after long night ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the == in the if statement

change this line:

```
if(strlen($number) = 7){
```

to:

```
if(strlen($number) == 7){
```

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I missed that its been a long night.